# why this line in code is showing me an error: napi.download_dataset(file, f"data/ {Current_Round} / {file}")

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

Below is the code.

```
# !pip install numerapi
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from numerapi import NumerAPI
napi = NumerAPI()
napi.download_dataset("v4/train.parquet", "train.parquet")

# To get the current round
Current_Round  =napi.get_current_round()
# Check all the files if they are parquet and int8, if so, download and store it .
for file in napi.list_datasets():
  if "parquet" and "int8" in file:
    if "train" in file or "validation" in file:
      napi.download_dataset(file, f"data/{file}")
    else:
      Path(f"data/{Current_Round}").mkdir(exist_ok= True, parents= True)
      napi.download_dataset(file, f"data/{Current_Round}/{file}")
Last line in above code is showing me an error, could you please help me with that.
```

Error message:

```
   FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-7e8816757f76> in <module>()
      8     else:
      9       Path(f"data/{Current_Round}").mkdir(exist_ok= True, parents= True)
---> 10       napi.download_dataset(file, f"data/{Current_Round}/{file}")

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numerapi/utils.py in download_file(url, dest_path, show_progress_bars)
     75     # Update progress bar to reflect how much of the file is already downloaded
     76     pbar.update(file_size)
---> 77     with open(dest_path, "ab") as dest_file:
     78         for chunk in req.iter_content(1024):
     79             dest_file.write(chunk)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/311/v3/numerai_live_data_int8.csv'
```

Comment: What is the error? Please add it to the question too

Comment: `if "parquet" and "int8" in file:` does not mean what you seem to think it does.  The only test being performed is `"int8" in file` - `"parquet"`, as a non-empty string, is unconditionally true.  Also, you are inconsistently inserting spaces in your directory and file names, so they probably don't actually match the files on your disk.

Comment: I just edit the question.

Comment: Let me paste my whole code, that way you will get better idea.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this:

```
      napi.download_dataset(file, f"data/ {Current_Round} / {file}")
```

and wound up with this diagnostic:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/ 311 / v3/numerai_live_data_int8.csv'
```

I don't know for certain,
but I would hazard a guess that you don't really have
a directory named SPACE311SPACE, more likely it's just three digits.
Similarly, perhaps SPACEv3 is really just "v3"?

Blanks within the f-string are significant,
they will appear in the filename.
Remove them if they are not desired.

---

EDIT

Numerapi offers a CLI.
You might try downloading the dataset from the command line.

The 2nd arg is optional:
https://numerapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/numerapi.html#numerapi.numerapi.NumerAPI.download_dataset

Omit it, and the downloaded file should
appear in the [current working directory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).

Comment: I removed all the unnecessary spaces, though i'm getting the same error.